# Application architecture/composition in F#

Tags: f#, inversion-of-control, composition, solid-principles

I have been doing SOLID in C# to a pretty extreme level in recent times and at some point realized I'm essentially not doing much else than composing functions nowadays. And after I recently started looking at F# again, I figured that it would probably be the much more appropriate choice of language for much of what I'm doing now, so I'd like to try and port a real world C# project to F# as a proof of concept. I think I could pull off the actual code (in a very un-idiomatic fashion), but I can't imagine what an architecture would look like that allows me to work in a similarly flexible fashion as in C#.

What I mean by this is that I have lots of small classes and interfaces that I compose using an IoC container, and I also use patterns like Decorator and Composite a lot. This results in an (in my opinion) very flexible and evolvable overall architecture that allows me to easily replace or extend functionality at any point of the application. Depending on how big the required change is, I might only need to write a new implementation of an interface, replace it in the IoC registration and be done. Even if the change is bigger, I can replace parts of the object graph while the rest of the application simply stands as it did before.

Now with F#, I don't have classes and interfaces (I know I can, but I think that's beside the point when I want to do actual functional programming), I don't have constructor injection, and I don't have IoC containers. I know I can do something like a Decorator pattern using higher order functions, but that doesn't quite seem to give me the same kind of flexibility and maintainability as classes with constructor injection.

Consider these C# types:

```cs
public class Dings
{
    public string Lol { get; set; }

    public string Rofl { get; set; }
}

public interface IGetStuff
{
    IEnumerable<Dings> For(Guid id);
}

public class AsdFilteringGetStuff : IGetStuff
{
    private readonly IGetStuff _innerGetStuff;

    public AsdFilteringGetStuff(IGetStuff innerGetStuff)
    {
        this._innerGetStuff = innerGetStuff;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Dings> For(Guid id)
    {
        return this._innerGetStuff.For(id).Where(d => d.Lol == "asd");
    }
}

public class GeneratingGetStuff : IGetStuff
{
    public IEnumerable<Dings> For(Guid id)
    {
        IEnumerable<Dings> dingse;

        // somehow knows how to create correct dingse for the ID

        return dingse;
    }
}
```

I'll tell my IoC container to resolve `AsdFilteringGetStuff` for `IGetStuff` and `GeneratingGetStuff` for its own dependency with that interface. Now if I need a different filter or remove the filter altogether, I may need the respective implementation of `IGetStuff` and then simply change the IoC registration. As long as the interface stays the same, I don't need to touch stuff **within** the application. OCP and LSP, enabled by DIP.

Now what do I do in F#?

```ml
type Dings (lol, rofl) =
    member x.Lol = lol
    member x.Rofl = rofl

let GenerateDingse id =
    // create list

let AsdFilteredDingse id =
    GenerateDingse id |> List.filter (fun x -> x.Lol = "asd")
```

I love how much less code this is, but I lose flexibility. Yes, I can call `AsdFilteredDingse` or `GenerateDingse` in the same place, because the types are the same - but how do I decide which one to call without hard coding it at the call site? Also, while these two functions are interchangeable, I now cannot replace the generator function inside `AsdFilteredDingse` without changing this function as well. This isn't very nice.

Next attempt:

```ml
let GenerateDingse id =
    // create list

let AsdFilteredDingse (generator : System.Guid -> Dings list) id =
    generator id |> List.filter (fun x -> x.Lol = "asd")
```

Now I have composability by making AsdFilteredDingse a higher order function, but the two functions are not interchangeable anymore. On second thought, they probably shouldn't be anyway.

What else could I do? I could mimic the "composition root" concept from my C# SOLID in the last file of the F# project. Most files are just collections of functions, then I have some kind of "registry", which replaces the IoC container, and finally there is one function that I call to actually run the application and that uses functions from the "registry". In the "registry", I know I need a function of type (Guid -> Dings list), which I'll call `GetDingseForId`. This is the one I call, never the individual functions defined earlier.

For the decorator, the definition would be

```ml
let GetDingseForId id = AsdFilteredDingse GenerateDingse
```

To remove the filter, I'd change that to

```ml
let GetDingseForId id = GenerateDingse
```

The downside(?) of this is that all functions that use other functions would sensibly have to be higher order functions, and my "registry" would have to map **all** functions that I use, because the actual functions defined earlier can't call any functions defined later, in particular not those from the "registry". I might also run into circular dependency issues with the "registry" mappings.

Does any of this make sense? How do you really build an F# application to be maintainable and evolvable (not to mention testable)?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This is easy once you realize that Object-Oriented Constructor Injection corresponds very closely to Functional **Partial Function Application**.

First, I'd write `Dings` as a record type:

```
type Dings = { Lol : string; Rofl : string }
```

In F#, the `IGetStuff` interface can be reduced to a single function with the signature

```
Guid -> seq<Dings>
```

A *client* using this function would take it as a parameter:

```
let Client getStuff =
    getStuff(Guid("055E7FF1-2919-4246-876E-1DA71980BE9C")) |> Seq.toList
```

The signature for the `Client` function is:

```
(Guid -> #seq<'b>) -> 'b list
```

As you can see, it takes a function of the target signature as input, and returns a list.

**Generator**

The generator function is easy to write:

```
let GenerateDingse id =
    seq {
        yield { Lol = "Ha!"; Rofl = "Ha ha ha!" }
        yield { Lol = "Ho!"; Rofl = "Ho ho ho!" }
        yield { Lol = "asd"; Rofl = "ASD" } }
```

The `GenerateDingse` function has this signature:

```
'a -> seq<Dings>
```

This is actually *more* generic than `Guid -> seq<Dings>`, but that's not a problem. If you only want to compose the `Client` with `GenerateDingse`, you could simply use it like this:

```
let result = Client GenerateDingse
```

Which would return all three `Ding` values from `GenerateDingse`.

**Decorator**

The original Decorator is a little bit more difficult, but not much. In general, instead of adding the Decorated (inner) type as a constructor argument, you just add it as a parameter value to a function:

```
let AdsFilteredDingse id s = s |> Seq.filter (fun d -> d.Lol = "asd")
```

This function has this signature:

```
'a -> seq<Dings> -> seq<Dings>
```

That's not quite what we want, but it's easy to compose it with `GenerateDingse`:

```
let composed id = GenerateDingse id |> AdsFilteredDingse id
```

The `composed` function has the signature

```
'a -> seq<Dings>
```

Just what we're looking for!

You can now use `Client` with `composed` like this:

```
let result = Client composed
```

which will return only `[{Lol = "asd"; Rofl = "ASD";}]`.

You don't *have* to define the `composed` function first; you can also compose it on the spot:

```
let result = Client (fun id -> GenerateDingse id |> AdsFilteredDingse id)
```

This also returns `[{Lol = "asd"; Rofl = "ASD";}]`.

**Alternative Decorator**

The previous example works well, but doesn't *really* Decorate a similar function. Here's an alternative:

```
let AdsFilteredDingse id f = f id |> Seq.filter (fun d -> d.Lol = "asd")
```

This function has the signature:

```
'a -> ('a -> #seq<Dings>) -> seq<Dings>
```

As you can see, the `f` argument is another function with the same signature, so it more closely resembles the Decorator pattern. You can compose it like this:

```
let composed id = GenerateDingse |> AdsFilteredDingse id
```

Again, you can use `Client` with `composed` like this:

```
let result = Client composed
```

or inline like this:

```
let result = Client (fun id -> GenerateDingse |> AdsFilteredDingse id)
```

For more examples and principles for composing entire applications with F#, see [my on-line course on Functional architecture with F#](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/functional-architecture-fsharp).

For more about Object-Oriented Principles and how they map to Functional Programming, see [my blog post on the SOLID principles and how they apply to FP](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/03/10/solid-the-next-step-is-functional).

Comment: Thanks Mark for the extensive answer. What I am still unclear on, however, is *where* to compose in an application with more than a trivial number of functions. I have in the mean time ported a small C# application to F# and posted it [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43893/first-real-world-f-application-how-good-idiomatic-is-it-long) for review; I have implemented the mentioned "registry" there as a `Composition` module, essentially a "poor man's DI" composition root. Is that a viable way to go?

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev As you may have noticed, I've updated the post by adding a link to a blog post that digs a bit deeper. When it comes to composition, one of the interesting things about F# is that the compiler prevents circular references, so [composition and decoupling is a lot safer than in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22248816/126014). The code you've linked to composes towards the end, so that looks good.

Comment: An alternate definition of the functions could be: `let AdsFilteredDingse = Seq.filter (fun d -> d.Lol = "asd")` and `let composed = GenerateDingse >> AdsFilteredDingse`. This way you get to use the function composition operator and you can leave out the id from AdsFilteredDingse. But again, as Mark mentioned, it's not really a decorator in the original OO sense of the word.

Comment: I've tried that, but it gives me a compiler error, although the signature of `composed` looks good: *"error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'composed' has been inferred to have generic type val composed : ('_a -> seq<Dings>) Either make the arguments to 'composed' explicit or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation."*