# Pass C# interfaces/classes to F#

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, f#

I have an existing project written in C#. I would like to move part of its business logic to F#.
MyObjectX is a C# class that runs scientific algorithms.
For MyObjectX to run it needs to implement a couple of interfaces, and some dependencies that are injected via methods (not constructor). Example:

```
public class MyObjectX(): IMathSolver, IBusinessSolver
{
    //private fields
    private int operationMode;
    private ISignalProvider signal;

    //Inject dependcy via method
    public void SetSignalProvider(ISignalProvider signal)
    {
        this.signal = signal;
    }

    //implemention of above interfaces
    public double MethodMathSolver()
    {
        this.signal.GetThreshold();
        //...
    }

    public double Method1BusinessSolver()
    {
    }

    public double Method2MathSolver(IResultProvider provider)
    {
        var x = provider.GetValueAtTime(0.1);
        //...
    }
}
```

So now I would like to implement MyObjectX in F#. What is the best way to do that so i can be as functional as possible in my code?

1. Make the existing C# MyObjectX behave as a wrapper/facade between the rest of C# classes and the F# library were the algorithms are implemented in F# modules.
2. Write a F# class of MyObjectX class that implements the interfaces, and probably call other F# modules.
3. Or non of them. please advise.

Also what is the best way to pass the dependencies of C# to F# like 'IResultProvider/ISignalProvider'? Do i need to use mutable variables that will get populated with the dependencies via functions in F#?

Please advise. if you can share a code sample i would be thankful.

Comment: I don't know F#, but all the CLR languages can reference each other's assemblies, so you should be able "see" all your C# objects from F# and vice-versa. I doubt that answers your question, but hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 6):

I think you could choose between 1 and 2. These are certainly the two most reasonable approaches.

I think that the option 2 might be better, because the F# implementation can then stay in simple F# modules using the most idiomatic F# style (such as passing functions around as arguments). The idiomatic F# code is not always easy to use from C#, so if you wrap it in an F# class that implements the required C# interfaces, you are hiding the "F# details" from the C# code, which is good.

Have a look at:

- [F# Component Design Guidelines](http://fsharp.org/about/index.html#specification) which says more things about how to design F# components in a way that makes them easy to use from C#.
- [Interfaces (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233207.aspx) on MSDN and [Interfaces page](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/interfaces/) at F# for Fun and Profit for more details about how to actually write such interface implementation in F#.

Comment: +1 In addition, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22543922/126014) for a stab at translating the `MyObjectX` class to F#.

Comment: +1. And I'm by no means an expert, but when I was creating F# library that was supposed to be also consumed on C# side, I went for 2nd option which worked *just perfect* (IMO).

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, the (more or less) direct translation of `MyObjectX` is

```
type MyObjectX() =
    let mutable operationMode = 0
    let mutable sp : ISignalProvider = Unchecked.defaultof<ISignalProvider>

    member this.SetSignalProvider signal = sp <- signal

    interface IMathSolver with
        member this.MethodMathSolver () = 
            sp.GetThreshold()
            //
            0.0
        member this.Method2MathSolver provider =
            let x = provider.GetValueAtTime 0.1
            //
            x

    interface IBusinessSolver with
        member this.Method1BusinessSolver () = 0.0
```

although I had to guess at a couple of the interface definitions.

However, **this isn't particularly functional**. For more information about moving from an object-oriented to a functional mindset, see

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22266609/126014
- http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/03/10/solid-the-next-step-is-functional

Answer (score 2):

So long as the interface is defined in an assembly referenced by the F# project you can just implement `MyObjectX` directly

```
type MyObjectX(signal : ISignalProvider) = 
   let mutable operationMode : int = 0;   // assuming this changes

   interface IMathSolver with 
       member x.GetMethodMathSolver() : double =
          signal.GetThreshold()
          // ... 
       member x.MethodBusinessSolver() : double = 
          ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the F# documentation. It is possible to create .NET classes and interfaces trivially and to use those within the language.

If you are looking to use IoC, you should have no problem injecting an F# implementation into a C# module and vice versa. Just have a play!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say go for (**1**).

That way, you'll have make your life easier referencing F# from other F# code, and the wrapper should be trivial to write. That will aslo add a level of indirection, letting you change the C# interface or the F# code without affecting the other side of the system.