# How to test functions in f# with external dependencies

Tags: f#

I am having a hard time trying to unit test F# code with external dependencies.

In C# (my background) you would typically have a class with a dependency passed in, which is then re-used. Apologies for my sample code, it's dumb but I'm just trying to illustrate my point.

```cs
public class Foo {

  IDependency d;
  public Foo(IDependency d) { this.d = d; }

  public int DoStuff(string bar) { return d.DoSomethingToStuff(bar); }

  public int DoMoreStuff(string bar) { 
     int i = d.DoSomethingToStuff(bar);
     return d.DoSomethingElseToStuff(bar, i);
  }
}
```

I'm trying to be pragmatic with F# and avoid using classes and interfaces (unless I need to interop with other .NET languages).

So my approach in this scenario is to have module and some functions with the dependencies passed in as functions. I found this tecnique [here](http://litemedia.info/dealing-with-dependencies-in-functional-programming)

```
module Foo

  let doStuff bar somethingFunc =
    somethingFunc bar

  let doMoreStuff bar somethingFunc somethingElseFunc =
    let i = somethingFunc bar
    somethingElseFunc bar i
```

The two problems I have with this code is:

1. I need to keep passing my dependencies around. In C#, it's passed in the constructor and re-used. You can imagine how quickly this gets out of control if `somethingFunc` is used in several places.
2. How do I unit test that dependencies have been executed? Again in C# I'd use a mocking framework and assert that certain methods were called.

How do I approach these problems in the F# world?

Comment: People probably won't like this comment, but: learn about side effects and see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Testing . "I'm trying to be pragmatic with F# and avoid using classes and interfaces" <- why? There's nothing pragmatic about this.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22266609/126014

Comment: @MauricioScheffer I have read several blog posts about treating F# as a functional language and using functions which operate on data structures rather than encapsulating data and behaviour. In any case, I don't want to treat F# like a classical OO language.

Comment: @VincePanuccio OO or not does not matter much... keep your code composable and as side-effect-free as you can.

Comment: @VincePanuccio the thing is there is no such shoehorning. It's useful to separate these three concepts in one's mind: objects, imperative, side-effects.

Answer (score 7):

It's not too difficult [mapping SOLID concepts like Dependency Injection to Functional-style F#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22266609/126014) - one of the keys is to realize that there's a [strong relationship between objects and closures](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/03/10/solid-the-next-step-is-functional).

In the present case, it would help to reorder the function arguments so that the 'dependencies' go first:

```
module Foo =    
  let doStuff somethingFunc bar =
    somethingFunc bar

  let doMoreStuff somethingFunc somethingElseFunc bar =
    let i = somethingFunc bar
    somethingElseFunc bar i
```

This will enable you to *compose* functions using **partial function application**:

```
let doStuff' = Foo.doStuff somethingImp
```

Now, `doStuff'` is a *closure*, because it closes over the concrete function `somethingImp`. Essentially, it captures the dependency, so it works just like an object with an injected dependency, and you can still invoke it with the remaining `bar` argument:

```
let bar = 42
let actual = doStuff' bar
```

---

**Testing**

Here's an example of using local functions as stubs:

```
module Tests =

    let ``Data flows correctly through doMoreStuff`` () =
        let somethingFunc bar =
            assert (bar = 42)
            1337
        let somethingElseFunc bar i =
            assert (bar = 42)
            assert (i = 1337)
            "Success"

        let actual = Foo.doMoreStuff somethingFunc somethingElseFunc 42

        assert (actual = "Success")
```

Here, for the sake of simplicity, I've used the [assert keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233187.aspx), but for proper tests, you should define a proper assertion function, or use your favourite assertion library.

Normally, I would tend to loosen the verification of input arguments, as it may make the Test Doubles too tightly coupled to a particular implementation. Also, keep in mind that you should [use Stubs for Queries, and Mocks for Commands](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/10/23/mocks-for-commands-stubs-for-queries) - in this example, there are only Queries, so all the Test Doubles are Stubs: although they do verify input *if* they are invoked, the test doesn't verify that they are invoked at all.

Comment: How do I unit test to ensure a function was called? Although it's easy enough to see with this example, for more complicated logic I'd want to verify certain functions were called.

Comment: @VincePanuccio "How do I unit test to ensure a function was called?" <- don't. Your unit tests should be just passing some data to the function being tested and then checking the result.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer That's the best approach, but that requires you to design without mutation, which I'm sure *you* know how to do :) Still, F# isn't a 'pure' Functional language, and sometimes, it can be helpful to verify that a Command was invoked - that's what I explain in my [Mocks for Commands, Stubs for Queries](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/10/23/mocks-for-commands-stubs-for-queries) article. TBC: in a pure Functional program, there are no Commands, and thus, no need for Mocks, so I'm not disagreeing. In an impure Functional program, you may have a few Commands, and thus, a few Mocks.